# Where to find core dumps from gcc and g++ compiled code?

Tags: compiling, gcc, g++, debugging

I compiled some C code, once with gcc, and then with g++, so I got two output executable files. When executing both files I found that it told me:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

But there is no sign of any core dumps in `/var/crash` to do with this (only old stuff) so where would they be (I wouldn't expect them to be in there, but just thought I'd mention that I had checked)? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20.

Comment: Whats the output of `ulimit -c`?

Comment: @heemayl: The output is `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Core dumping is disabled by default in Ubuntu by setting the maximum dumping file size to 0 for all users.

You can check this by:

```
ulimit -c
```

By default it would show 0.

Now to enable core dumping, set the size to the value you want (or `unlimited`).

For example, setting the maximum dumping file size as 4 KB:

```
ulimit -c 8
```

`-c` takes block numbers with each block being 512 Bytes.

Setting to `unlimited` (Not recommended):

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

This will change the limit for the current user and not permanently. To make the changes effective for users selectively and permanently, you should edit the `/etc/security/limits.conf` file and set your desired values.